# MySQL multi-muster replication

Tags: mysql, tungsten-replicator, multi-master-replication

I need to create multi-muster replication using 4 MySQL servers.
After research, I found 2 way to do this:

1) Ring connection.
... Server_1 -> Server_2 -> Server_3 -> Server_4 -> Server_1 ...

2) Using Tungsten Replicator.
http://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/wiki/TRCMultiMasterInstallation#Install_a_four_masters_replication

Anyone used them in production mode?
Which way is better? 
Perhaps there are other ways to create MySQL multi-muster replication?

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, MySQL cluster may a solution for you - http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/

Comment: It is - http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/cluster/ "It is available as both open source and commercial editions."

Answer (score 0):

I've used Tungsten in production and it works great. I haven't used it for multi-master but I see no reason it shouldn't work.

Depending on your requirements for how close the slave have to be each master you could also try a Round Robin solution where the slave runs each master for a fixed time and the switched to the next one.

This is for MySQL 5.5 and older http://mysqlmusings.blogspot.se/2011/04/round-robin-multi-source-in-pure-sql.html
And this is for MySQL 5.6 http://mysqlmusings.blogspot.se/2012/10/round-robin-replication-using-gtid.html

The first one would actually work fine for 5.6 as well but in 5.6 there is better support for a cleaner solution.